# PHP Date format not available in CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, contacts, import

I'm hoping someone can help me with a date problem. I'm importing contacts from my Drupal 7 build and our member's birth dates are not showing up. The short custom code as per the php manual is m/d/Y but that is not an option in the CiviCRM date settings. They offer mm/dd/yyyy. But when I select mm/dd/yyyy, i get repeated values eg. 0505/1313/1955195519551955. Has anyone had this problem and is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you show here? /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?action=update&id=3&reset=1    as a format?  How are you importing your contacts? Have you tried using Excel(etc.) to reformat the date to a different format Civi accepts?

Comment: @Zachary I think the poster is referring to the options given on the contact import page, which aren't php format strings just human display. So this sounds like a bug maybe.

Comment: I just did a test on the public demo at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org using Birth Date `05/13/1955` and choosing `mm/dd/yyyy` and it imported correctly. What version of civi are you using?

Comment: can you past your csv file content 1-2 line?, may be  date field values are incorrect while formatting it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses. Demerit was closest to what I needed. Turns out the default date option was year-month-date so I needed to match that before I could re-format the display to what I wanted which was 'September 15th, 1952'